# How can I replace or fix old www.dynarch.com calendar

Tags: javascript, php, datepicker

I have this ancient calendar in use with my simple project management program. It stopped working, date picker pop-up does not show anymore.

I checked from Chromium console what the problem is. I got this error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined
at Calendar._displayWeekdays (calendar.js:15)
at Calendar.create (calendar.js:15)
at HTMLImageElement.triggerEl.(/task/anonymous function) (https://www.xxxx.xxx/task/jscalendar/calendar-setup.php?format=%25d%2F%25m%2F%25y:34:2702)
Calendar._displayWeekdays @ calendar.js:15
Calendar.create @ calendar.js:15
triggerEl.(anonymous function) @ calendar-setup.php?format=%d%2F%m%2F%y:34
```

I have no idea how to fix it or how to replace this old datepicker.
I updated it to newer version, it didn't help. I updated jquery, it didn't help.

I'm totally lost now how to get it working again.

I'm really grateful if someone could help me to fix this problem.

Here is calendar.js file in question : [calendar.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1q5rBcX9SbP31ire7xwuO9IpiLt7q6U44)

Here is calendar-setup.php : [calendar-setup.php](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1G8E6thAEl3_4YfhMbkYbslj0HG5_amSU)

There is also calendar-setup.js, here : [calendar-setup.js](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1VPPsX1RyhWn7R0UQ8o9fdDdm9tfdc9ar)

Comment: Edit and post more Your code especially with this property 'replace'.

Comment: I still see only error. Don't looks like You edited question.

Comment: Edit Question no add to comment. And place a source file no bundle file.

Comment: Okay I'll move these files to my question

Comment: I don't need it. XD I just try to help You get to know how You should ask a question. No one will help You because they don't see calendar.js file. Thay will just tag Your question as unsolvable or arrow down becouse thay can't do any thing without this file.

Comment: Yes I understand. Now all the needed files are included in my question

Comment: Now You need to pray that some one want to read those boundled files and find solution. XD